# sort row groupings in datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, datatables, grouping

I am using datables and jquery row grouping..

here is the **[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d03ebwdj/)**

as you can see it's a normal table but with row grouping, the **green colored ones are the row group,** but there is no way to sort them with a click like I can with the Name and Score column, the only way to sort them is changing the **`sGroupingColumnSortDirection:`** to `"asc"` or `"desc"` in this code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#main').dataTable({
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bFilter": false,
        "bInfo": false
    }).rowGrouping({
        sGroupingColumnSortDirection: "asc", //this one is repsonsible for the group sortings
        bExpandableGrouping: true
    });
});
```

that way it works, but the user doesn't have an option or a way to sort the groupings..

I thought of making a select drop-down, so it will sort the groupings corresponding to what the user selects.

```
<label>
Sort place by:
<select>
  <option value="place">Ascending</option>
  <option value="place">Descending</option>
</select>
</label>
```

so is it possible to sort the grouping with this select drop-down?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, provide an id for the drop down, and give proper values to the options. Then, on the "onchange" event of the dropdown, you need to call the datatable "fnSort" function.

```
<select id="selectSort">
    <option value="Ascending">Ascending</option>
    <option value="Descending">Descending</option>
</select>
```

Include the following code in your jquery document.ready section.

```
$("#selectSort").change(function() {

    var oTable = $('#main').dataTable();
    var sOption = $(this).val();
    if(sOption == "Ascending") {
        var sType = 'asc';
    }
    else {
        var sType = 'desc';
    }

    //code for two columns, change if you have more columns.
    oTable.fnSort( [ [0,sType], [1,sType] ] );  


});
```

Updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d03ebwdj/1/

**Update:**
In your grouping approach, it would be difficult to sort based on groupings. What you can do is, create a third column as "Place". Set it to hidden. You can highlight the grouping using "drawCallback" function. Please refer [here](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_grouping.html)

Comment: I have tried the demo but you sorting by names, I want it to sort by group the green ones, look at my demo again.. am taking about the sGroupingColumnSortDirection: the green ones.

Comment: what i meant was this http://videobam.com/Runyr, but since you said it's hard, I think I will just have to look another way or cancel this datatables.

Comment: two year and still no solution - is it not possible to sort the groups? if it is possible, I also want the contents (children) of the groupings sortable. Any idea how to make the groupings sortable? 
--Baskets: 
     Wire
     Reed
--Handles: 
     Knobs
     Pulls
 
I want the reordered to: 
--Handles: 
     Knobs
     Pulls
--Baskets: 
     Wire
     Reed